# Populate div with .load based on drop down selection

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

Alright this feels like a basic thing, but im struggling to make it work -
What I'm trying to accomplish is a drop down list with about 45 county's, when one is selected, an empty div in the body will load with a div from another html page (where I'm going to house the 45 divs of corresponding location information).

Intending on using an ajax load style event

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#county-result").load("county_list.html #county1");
});
</script>
```

But to make the script less heavy I would want the dropdown value to be its matching county div id to populate that part of the load function (rather then writing 45 individual ones)

Ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Something like `var county = $("#myDropdown").val(); $("#county-result").load("county_list.html #" + county);`

Comment: If it were me, I'd use JSON as my data source and populate the divs using a template and iterating over the JSON object and looking for the selected id

Comment: @DelightedD0D I agree with you, I would have probably done the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/te5qCPtwXNT9sV3npzhF?p=preview) for you! I hope it helps

What I'm basically doing here is, I'm adding a change event listener to a select (dropdown) And I make sure my divs in the countries html file have the same id's as my option values in my main file (The one where you will have the dropdown menu)

So if you want information about germany you have to make sure a countries option and div will look a bit like this

`<option value="germany">germany</option>`

```
<div id="germany">
    <h1>Berlin</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: ahhh you angel of a human being, thank you so much! I was just confusing myself on how to pull all the things together,and thats perfect.

Comment: @lucy MacGregor I am more than happy I could have helped! If you have any other questions make sure you ask them! Goodluck with whatever you are making :)

Comment: It dosent seem to work in any other browser besides mozilla, when its on my local storage :/ does this kind of script usually need to be on a staging server etc for the javascript to work?

Comment: When I first created this script, I made it on my local machine and ran it on chrome. When you say local storage you are referring to your local machine right? Also are you using the right paths?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit broad. But, if I needed to work with information related to 45 counties and needed to display the info for the county selected from a dropdown, I'd use JSON as my data source and populate the divs using a template and iterating over the JSON object and looking for the selected id.

The below is an example of how that might work. Note that I'm actually building the select box options dynamically based on the dataset itself and the setup allows you to easily update the data if needed.

**Note** how you get the JSON is up to you. I have hard coded it for this example but you could get it via an ajax request or using `.get()`, `.load()`, etc..

```js
var myCountyInfo = {
  counties: [{
    name: 'County 1',
    id:123,
    locationInfo: {
      lat: 453245,
      lng: 45545,
      avgTemp: '75f',
      population: '5 B.'
    }
  }, {
    name: 'County 2',
    id:456,
    locationInfo: {
      lat: 11221,
      lng: 542222,
      avgTemp: '59f',
      population: '2 B.'
    }
  }, {
    name: 'County 3',
    id:789,
    locationInfo: {
      lat: 88555,
      lng: 54757,
      avgTemp: '58f',
      population: '1 B.'
    }
  }]
}

function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
  var counties = [];
  $.each(data, function() {
    counties.push('<option value="'+this.id+'">' + this.name + '</option>');
  });
  $select.append(counties.join(''));
}

function populateTableRow($tableBody, data, selectedCountyId) {
  var county;
  $.each(data, function() {
    if (this.id == selectedCountyId) {
      county = this;
      return false;
    }
  });
  $tableBody.html('<tr>'+
                     '<td>' + county.name + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + county.locationInfo.lat +'</td>'+
                     '<td>' + county.locationInfo.lng + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + county.locationInfo.avgTemp + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + county.locationInfo.population + '</td>'+
                  '</tr>');


}
populateSelectBoxes($('#my-select'), myCountyInfo.counties);

$('#my-select').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var selection = $this.val();
  populateTableRow($('#my-table tbody'), myCountyInfo.counties, selection);
});
```

```css
td,th{
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="my-select"></select>

<table id="my-table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>County</th>
      <th>Lat.</th>
      <th>Lng.</th>
      <th>Avg Temp</th>
      <th>Population</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I was actually planning to use a similar approach, but to keep it simple for OP I decided to go with a more simple approach, +1 for a different way of doing things eitherway!