# Using 2 drop downs to create 2 side-by-side table rows to compare data - JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Thanks for your help in advance. I've been hacking together some code for a page on my website and I'm at a roadblock.

The goal is to have two drop down selections that produce two table rows (that display in vertical columns side by side for a  comparison table.

I know the code is not correct because I'm pulling in the same values twice but I'm not sure where to make the changes to make the second dropdown pull in data from a second career.

As it works now, both dropdowns generate the same table row. updating one dropdown overwrites the existing results.

here is a https://jsfiddle.net/0qwz497e/ that shows where I'm at now.

I also intend to make the drop downs searchable but want to get this ironed out first. One thought I had was changing the call event to not update until a "compare" button was clicked. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style>
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr { display: block; float: left; }
th, td { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="my-select"></select>
<select name="" id="my-select-2"></select>

<table id="my-table" border="1" style="width:100%">
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

  </body>

</html>
<script>
  var myCareerInfo = {
  careers: [{
    name: 'Occupational Therapy',
    id:123,
    careerInfo: {
      salary: 'Salary: $68,555',
      education: 'Education: Masters',
      skills: 'Example, Example, Example',
      description: 'Occupational therapist help people with their ADLs. They blah blah blah...'
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Phlebotomist',
    id:456,
    careerInfo: {
      salary: 'Salary: $46,753',
      education: 'Education: Certificate Program',
      skills: 'Example, Example, Example',
      description: 'Phlebotomists draw blood. They blah blah blah...'
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Physical Therapist',
    id:789,
    careerInfo: {
      salary: 'Salary: $88,555',
      education: 'Education: Doctorate',
      skills: 'Example, Example, Example',
      description: 'Physical therapist help people recover function after an injury. They blah blah blah...'
    }
  }]
}

function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
  var careers = [];
  $.each(data, function() {
    careers.push('<option value="'+this.id+'">' + this.name + '</option>');
  });
  $select.append(careers.join(''));
}

function populateTableRow($tableBody, data, selectedCareerId) {
  var career;
  $.each(data, function() {
    if (this.id == selectedCareerId) {
      career = this;
      return false;
    }
  });
  $tableBody.html('<tr style="width:50%">'+
                     '<td>' + career.name + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career.careerInfo.salary +'</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career.careerInfo.education + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career.careerInfo.skills + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career.careerInfo.description + '</td>'+
                  '</tr>'+
                  '<tr style="width:50%">'+
                     '<td>' + career.name + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career.careerInfo.salary +'</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career.careerInfo.education + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career.careerInfo.skills + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career.careerInfo.description + '</td>'+
                  '</tr>');


}
populateSelectBoxes($('#my-select'), myCareerInfo.careers);

$('#my-select').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var selection = $this.val();
  populateTableRow($('#my-table tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selection);
});
populateSelectBoxes($('#my-select-2'), myCareerInfo.careers);

$('#my-select-2').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var selection = $this.val();
  populateTableRow($('#my-table tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selection);
});
</script>
```

The bulk of the code came from @DelightedD0D and their original response to [another dropdown question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690155/populate-div-with-load-based-on-drop-down-selection/35690868#35690868) I don't yet have the reputation to comment on that response directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many approaches to solve it.

I tried a (one of the possible ones) conservative solution over your code.

You can see it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qwz497e/3/).

In summary:

```
function populateTableRow($tableBody, data, selectBoxes) {
  var career = [];

  selectBoxes.map(function(s){
        var currentId = s.val();
      return data.map(function(item){
            if(item.id == currentId) career.push(item);
      })
  });
  [...] (See jsfiddle for the rest)
};
```

...

```
var selectBoxes = [
  populateSelectBoxes($('#my-select'), myCareerInfo.careers),
  populateSelectBoxes($('#my-select-2'), myCareerInfo.careers),
]

$('#my-select').change(function() {
  populateTableRow($('#my-table tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selectBoxes);
});


$('#my-select-2').change(function() {
  populateTableRow($('#my-table tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selectBoxes);
});
```

...but, in fact, in my opinion would be better to directly call populateTableRow() without parameters and take data directly by scope inheritance. Better enclosing the whole thing in a single closure. But, as I said, I tried to make as less changes to your code as possible. ;-)

So, the point here is that I directly passed references to both selectboxes because you are overwriting the whole table each time (so you need to know both selection values).

Other approach would be to prebuild the whole table and only update the cells of the right column.

And a third one, to surround your function inside a closure in which state you could remember all previous selections even only passing a single select box change.

**NOTE:** A few years ago I amused myself with a similar problem. If you are trying to visually compare characteristics of different things (not only two) maybe my solution could be interesting for you: [iCompare](https://github.com/bitifet/icompare) I called it.

(Demostration link doesn't work because that server died time ago... I apologize for that).

It helps in comparsions because user can dynamically remove non interesting items and/or characteristics and the characteristics that are common to all items are also removed from the comparsion table and showed in a summary (of common values) box.

Comment: Thanks Bitifet. I had to tweak it a little to get the data cells to line up between the two columns if the data was different lengths (in the example, career 1 + 2 match up great but adding Physical therapy skewed the rows). I was able to get it running with your help. You = Lifesaver! Thanks!

Comment: I noticed something strange in the table render ordering, but I wouldn't waste time in understanding working code. Now I notice css tweaking.
But, if you are anyway rewriting whole table code, why not to simply put it in the usual order?
You also (in both cases, of course: I avoided it to minimize code changes) can iterate over career to both avoid code repetition and being able to add more columns if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I created two tables and lined them side by side for two dropdowns. Hope this helps..

```
        <select name="" id="my-select"></select>
    <select name="" id="my-select-2"></select>
    <div>
    <table id="my-table1" border="1" style="float:left; width:49%;">
      <thead>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table id="my-table2" border="1" style="width:49%; float:right;">
      <thead>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
        </div>

    <script>
      var myCareerInfo = {
      careers: [{
        name: 'Career 1',
        id:123,
        careerInfo: {
          salary: 453245,
          education: 45545,
          skills: '75f',
          description: '5 B.'
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Career 2',
        id:456,
        careerInfo: {
          salary: 11221,
          education: 542222,
          skills: '59f',
          description: '2 B.'
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Physical Therapist',
        id:789,
        careerInfo: {
          salary: 'Salary: $88,555',
          education: 'Education: Doctorate',
          skills: 'Example, Example, Example',
          description: 'Physical therapist help people recover function after an injury. They blah blah blah...'
        }
      }]
    }

    function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
      var careers = [];
      $.each(data, function() {
        careers.push('<option value="'+this.id+'">' + this.name + '</option>');
      });
      $select.append(careers.join(''));
    }

    function populateTableRow($tableBody, data, selectedCareerId) {
      var career;
      $.each(data, function() {
        if (this.id == selectedCareerId) {
          career = this;
          return false;
        }
      });
      $tableBody.html('<tr style="width:100%">'+
                         '<td>' + career.name + '</td>'+
                         '<td>' + career.careerInfo.salary +'</td>'+
                         '<td>' + career.careerInfo.education + '</td>'+
                         '<td>' + career.careerInfo.skills + '</td>'+
                         '<td>' + career.careerInfo.description + '</td>'+
                      '</tr>');


    }
    populateSelectBoxes($('#my-select'), myCareerInfo.careers);

    $('#my-select').change(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var selection = $this.val();

      populateTableRow($('#my-table1 tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selection);
    });
    populateSelectBoxes($('#my-select-2'), myCareerInfo.careers);

    $('#my-select-2').change(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var selection = $this.val();
      populateTableRow($('#my-table2 tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selection);
    });

    // initialize tables
    populateTableRow($('#my-table1 tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, $('#my-select').val());
    populateTableRow($('#my-table2 tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, $('#my-select-2').val());


    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks T.Shah I put your advice into action and it helped me figure out where some of my issues were. I ended up going with @bitifet 's solution. While your answer did everything I asked in the question, I couldn't get the rows of the tables to line up with each other if the data was different lengths. Thanks for your answer